# Why is onCreateView in Fragment called twice after device rotation in Android?

Tags: android, rotation, fragment

I have simple activity and fragment transaction. What i noticed that on configuration changes oncreateView of Fragment is called twice. Why is this happening?

Activity Code Here :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Activity created");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();

    addFragmentToActivity(manager,
            fragment,
            R.id.root_activity_create
    );
}

public static void addFragmentToActivity (FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                          Fragment fragment,
                                          int frameId)
                                           {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(frameId, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
    }
```

Fragment Code Here :

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: When configuration changes occurs , `Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()`)

Comment: " What i noticed that on configuration changes oncreateView of Fragment is called twice". Does that mean onCreateView is called twice for single rotation?

Comment: Yes it is  is called twice for single rotation

Comment: Ok one doubt, first on portrait onCreateView is called once, if changed to  landscape onCreateView is called twice or once ?

Comment: @BaluSangem once for every rotation

Comment: @VivekMishra if that is the quesion, Then it will happen like that only .Because onCreate() of activity will be called for every rotation

Comment: You can check this - https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a

Comment: @BaluSangem yes a new instance of activity is created on rotation

Comment: Whn application starts for the first time only one oncreateView, but on rotation change 2 oncreateViews i called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On first load `onCreateView()` is called once

But onRotation `onCreateView()` is called twice

why ?

Because of this `transaction.replace(frameId, fragment);` Really? Yes,I mean because of `fragment` .You already have one fragment onFirst load, When you rotate `onCreate()` will be called once again, so now fragment manager has old fragment ,so it methods will execute(once),and next you are doing transaction `replace()` which will remove old fragment and replace it with new once and again(`onCreateView()` will be called for second time). This is repeating for every rotation.

If you use `transaction.add(frameId, fragment,UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_EVERY_TRANSACTION)` you would know the reason. for every rotatation, no.of `onCreateView()` calls will increase by 1. that means you are adding fragments while not removing old ones.

But solution is to use old fragments.

in `onCreate()`of activity

```
    val fragment = fragmentmanager.findFrgmentByTag("tag")
     val newFragment : BlankFragment
     if(fragment==null){
       newFragment = BlankFragment()
     }else{
       newFragment = fragment as BlankFragment()
     }
     //use newFragment
```

Hope this solves confusion

Comment: "for every rotatation, no.of onCreateView() calls will increase by 1" is not true. Look at my answer. Your answer is only half right

Comment: You have to give different tags for every `add` transaction( i mentioned `UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_EVERY_TRANSACTION`) , it will increase.Please try

Comment: oh ok indeed that will happen when adding tags, sorry didn't read your answer completely

Comment: This answer is basically the same as mine then. The point is that onCreateView is called twice: once for the fragment that is restored by android, once for the replace of that fragment by a new fragment. your solution is better if a reference to the fragment is needed

Comment: @PrisonMike yes solution is same. But by using `add` transaction,we can know what is causing all these problems. I wanted to explain that.

Comment: Just one question, how manager on configuration change has old fragmnet if it is also destryed with conf changes?

Comment: onDestroy() called to do final cleanup of the fragment's state. so only state is gone, but instance is still alive which hold by FragmentManager(you will add instance to `mAdded:ArrayList<Fragment>`in `FragmentManager` ,when doing transaction ).

Comment: You are a legend!

Answer (score 8):

Android automatically restores the state of its views after rotation. You don't have to call addFragmentToActivity again after rotation. The fragment will automatically be restored for you!

In your case, it happens twice because:
 1. Android restores the fragment, its onCreateView is called
 2. You replace the restored fragment with your own fragment, the oncreateview from that fragment is called too

do this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
{
     addFragmentToActivity(manager, fragment, R.id.test);
}
```